# Installation Failure of VirtualBox Extension

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, password, extension

I'm attempting to add  the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack 4.2.12 to my VirtualBox Settings. When it asks me for authorization, I enter the same password I use with Ubuntu Software Center or any other request for authorization. I get this message after 3 attempts:

```
Failed to install the Extension Pack /home/camraman1/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.12-84980.vbox-extpack.

The installer failed with exit code 1: GNOME_SUDO_PASS
Sorry, try again.
GNOME_SUDO_PASS
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts.
Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ExtPackManager
Interface: IExtPackManager {3295e6ce-b051-47b2-9514-2c588bfe7554}
```

I'm a newbie in the world of Linux. A Windows user all of my life (except a brief time with Commodore), so I'm a old guy in a young person's world. Help me out. I've read and reread the manual. Obviously there are a few steps I must have missed or just don't understand.

I've created my VM using Windows XP. I've added myself to the Vboxusers group.

My system information is listed below.

```
-Computer-
   Processor            : 2x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU 6400  @ 2.13GHz
   Memory               : 1010MB (701MB used)
   Operating System     : Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
   Date/Time            : Tue 07 May 2013 11:21:38 AM CDT
-Display-
   Resolution           : 1680x1050 pixels
 OpenGL Renderer        : Unknown
   X11 Vendor           : The X.Org Foundation
-Multimedia-
   Audio Adapter        : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
-Input Devices-
   Power Button
   Power Button
   AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
   HDA Intel Line
   HDA Intel Front Mic
   HDA Intel Rear Mic
   HDA Intel Front Headphone
   HDA Intel Line-Out
   ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse
-Printers (CUPS)-
   Deskjet-3050-J610-series : Default
-SCSI Disks-
   NEC DVD_RW ND-3520A
   ATA Hitachi HDS72168
   TOSHIBA External USB 3.0
   Seagate FreeAgentDesktop
   PNY USB 2.0 FD
```

What other information do you need from me so I can begin using the VirtualBox software to it's fullest potential? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I know it is late but I have the same problem and this is a solution that works:

1. cd to the directory of extension pack file. (for ease of access, move it first to home).
2. run this command:

   `sudo VBoxManage extpack install <tarball>`

where tarball is the full name of the extension pack file. BEWARE! Do not rename the file before hand. It should start with something like Oracle_VM_* and finished with *.vbox-extpack. Type that without the * mark, and then just hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

Move the package that you are installing the following directory:

```
mv name package  /usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks
```

Then go to the directory where you moved:

```
cd /usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks
```

Install the package:

```
sudo VBoxManage extpack install name package
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to move the file to that specific directory? And `package` is not correct - it has to be the file name. Apart from that: nothing new compared with junda's answer.